# Add endpoint in Cloud Integration service

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-integration

I failed to add endpoint in Cloud Integration service, following the steps below:

- Login to Bluemix
- Create a Cloud Integration service
- click on Secure connections tab
- Download the connector and install it on the controller node
- provide the public key
- Refresh the connection. It should show connected
- try to add the endpoint It is giving error fail to connect endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Each time that you create a new basic connection, a new installation .tar file is created specific to that installation. They all have unique /home/nativeapiadmin/mgmt.tunnel files that are configured specifically for that connector. If you want to reuse an existing copy of the installation, you must edit the mgmt.tunnel file with the correct host name or IP address, and port numbers.Then, restart the connector.

If above does not resolve your problem, run the following procedure to clean up and recreate the endpoint:

- delete your basic connector from cloud integration
- create a new basic connector, with a new name
- Download the Linux 64-bit installer and make sure the file size is  around 844,128 bytes
- remove the older connector from the system

  - delete the "nativeapiadmin" user and the user's directory
  - delete the known_host file in the /root/.ssh directory
- reinstall the connector, please read the INSTALL_README file that is included in the zip
- upload the id_rsa.pub key from same machine as connector was installed
- create the endpoint